# Adding PS1's "user@machine" to the exported version of an org-babel shell block

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel, shell

I am using org-babel for running shell commands.
I'd like to export the code block as if it was running from the terminal, so adding "user@machine" before each command.

When I export the org file to latex I am getting the shell commands only.

For example:

```
#+begin_src shell :results output replace :exports both
  netstat -an | grep 192
#+end_src
```

Gets outputted as:

netstat -an | grep 192

And I'd like it to be exported as:

```
  user@machine ~ $: netstat -an | grep 192
```